# Homeless woman abandons young daughter

Tags: identify-this-movie, drama

A woman loses her home. She is homeless and pregnant, she births a baby girl. She tries to raise it but in the end she buys her a necklace and tells her she's gonna get sandwiches and leaves her. The woman has organised with someone to adopt her girl. The adopters go and get the girl when the mom left her alone to get the food. The mother has organised this. Also there is a scene where the girl nurse in a hospital and she likes it there, she doesn't wanna leave. The director in the ending titles indicates how many people are homeless in the United States. The whole story takes place somewhere in the United States. I think sometime in the movie the woman works in a factory and when the girl is still a baby the man who rents them the apartment they live in tries to rape her.

I saw it on Greek TV in 2003.

Comment: Can you recall what year you saw the movie, or can you recall what year/decade you believe the movie was released in?

Comment: i saw it in 2003 or earlier i think....

Comment: Did you see it on DVD?  Cinema?  Plain old TV?

Comment: I saw it on greek tv. Sure during 2003

Comment: May be it's [God Bless the Child (1988)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0095227/)?

Comment: @knut Of course.

Answer (score 3):

May be it's [God Bless the Child (1988)?](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0095227/)

Storyline:

> Single mother, Theresa Johnson, becomes homeless, loses her job and
> tries to survive with her young daughter, Hillary, through charities
> and public shelters.
>
> Written by Herman Seifer